# Import the second tkinter page into the first tkinter page - python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter, import, split

I have problem/question about tkinter...
I have two tkinter apps - [`first.py`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAEwa.png) and [`second.py`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rODuI.png)- I want to import `second.py` into `first.py` and run it in `first.py` window (not in **tk** and **tk#2** but still in **tk**. *(I hope you understand me.)*
 So is there a possible way to do it?
*Of course, it's much easier to create just one script ... but I'm creating a more complex application, and splitting a script into multiple scripts is essential for me.*

Here is a simple script for `first.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from second import scnd

def frst():

    root = tk.Tk()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg = "grey", width = 400, height = 400, relief = "groove")
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill="both")

    label = tk.Label(root, text = "First page!", bg = "grey",fg = "white")
    canvas.create_window(100, 100, window = label)

    button = tk.Button(root, text = "Open second page", bg = "blue", fg = "white", command = scnd)
    canvas.create_window(200, 200, window = button)

    root.mainloop()
frst()
```

And here is a simple script for `second.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def scnd():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg = "grey", width = 400, height = 400, relief = "groove")
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill="both")

    label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Second page!", bg = "grey",fg = "white")
    canvas.create_window(100, 100, window = label2)

    button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Open first page", bg = "blue", fg = "white", command = None)
    canvas.create_window(200, 200, window = button2)
    root.mainloop()
```

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you don't want to create new tk windows, don't call `Tk()` and `mainloop` in second script. Put all content from first script into frame, and then call function `scnd` with button, give parameters `root` and `frame`. When you run second script you will want to destroy old frame and put everything from new script into new frame, so in the future you will also destroy it. Hope it helps.

First script:

```
def frst():
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg="grey", width=400, height=400, relief="groove")
    canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill="both")

    label = tk.Label(frame, text="First page!", bg="grey", fg="white")
    canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=label)

    button = tk.Button(frame, text="Open second page", bg="blue", fg="white", command=lambda: scnd(root, frame))
    canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=button)

    root.mainloop()


frst()
```

Second script:

```
def scnd(root, frame):
    def clicked():
        print('click!')
    frame.destroy() 
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="grey", width=400, height=400, relief="groove")
    canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill="both")

    label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Second page!", bg="grey", fg="white")
    canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=label2)

    button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Open first page", bg="blue", fg="white", command=clicked)
    canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=button2)
```